# Using GMLib and needing to zoom to a city level much like the viewport option

Tags: delphi, gmlib

Using GMLib in delphi an would like to zoom to the city level and center it.

Answer (score 0):

To center map, you need to change GMMap.RequiredProp.Center properties or call GMMap.SetCenter method.

To zoom to the city level, you need to know the viewport of the city and call GMMap.LatLngBoundsSetBounds method